# Existe uma função no WordPress para controlar páginas filhas?

Tags: wordpress

Estou procurando uma pequena função no WordPress que faça o seguinte:

```
Se (esta página for filha desta outra) { mostre este menu }

Mas (caso esta página seja filha desta outra) { mostre este outro menu }
```

A hierarquia das páginas é a seguinte:

```
Doutor
     Home
     Currículo
     Consultório
     Contato

Doutora
     Home
     Currículo
     Consultório
     Contato
```

Pois dois médicos dividirão conteúdo num mesmo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na hora de imprimir os menus, pode testar por `is_page()` e dentro desse bloco conferir a propriedade `$post->post_parent` (`post_parent` é uma coluna na tabela `wp_posts`).

No `header.php`:

```
<?php
    if( is_page() ) {
        global $post; 
        if( $post->post_parent == '2' ) // ID da página DOUTOR
            wp_nav_menu( $args_is_doutor );
        else if( $post->post_parent == '4' ) // ID da página DOUTORA
            wp_nav_menu( $args_is_doutora );
        else
            wp_nav_menu( $args_is_page ); // Outras páginas
    }
    else {
        wp_nav_menu( $args_is_not_page ); // Qualquer outro tipo de template
    }
?>
```